# How to create a material with base color layers?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I know how to create a material with layers, but texture layers. I need base color layers, because my game is low poly

Answer (score 0):

did you try using vector3d (or something like that, i can't remember the exact name) ?